# stop tableviewcontroller scrolling

Tags: objective-c, scroll, uitableview

I am adding a textview to UITableviewController's view and now I want to stop the scrolling of view of UITableviewController. 
But I am unable to do so. As its a view so no enable and disable scrolling properties like table view are existing.
Any ideas???

Comment: Please tag your post with the correct environment/language so people know what they are working with without having to decipher the whole question.

Answer (score 4):

```
self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

where self is your UITableViewController